# Properties of the solution of the heat equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, real-analysis, parabolic-pde

Note 1: the following question has been post on Math Stackexchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1531019/the-study-of-the-properties-of-the-solution-of-heat-equation) but receive no respond. So I post it here to get more attention.

Note 2: This is my research problem, but the original problem has more complicated operator other then just $\Delta$ below. And it works in $BV$ space. But here I give the most simplified version so that to have some ideas...

---

I am studying the following basic heat equation. (All notations follows Evans book)
\begin{align}
u_t -\Delta u =0 &\text{ in }\mathbb R^2\times(0,\infty)\\
u=u_0 &\text{ on }\mathbb R^2\times\{t=0\}
\end{align}
i.e., the Cauchy problem. Here we assume $u_0\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ and $u_0$ is non-negative.

Let $u(x,t)$ denote the standard solution so that 
$$
u(x,t):=\frac{1}{4\pi t}\int_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}u_0(y)dy \tag 1
$$

Now given a function $a(x)\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ so that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)\,dx=0,\,\,\int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u_0(x)\,dx=C = \int_{\mathbb R^2}(a(x))^2dx, \tag 3
$$
where $C>0$ is a constant. (Note the above equation does not mean $u_0=a$)

---

Now I need to study the following equation:
$$
f(t):=\int_{\mathbb R^2} [u(x,t)-u_0(x)]\cdot\partial_t u(x,t)\,dx - \int_{\mathbb R^2} \partial_tu(x,t)\cdot a(x)\,dx. \tag 2
$$

My questions:

1. Assume that there exist $t_0>0$ so that $f(t_0)=0$. Prove that for all $0<t<t_0$, $f(t)<0$; and for all $t>t_0$, $f(t)>0$. And I expect $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.
2. Give a condition on $u_0$ so that there exists such $t_0>0$. (the condition can not be $u_0$ is a constant.)

---

What I tried so far is put $(1)$ into $(2)$ and see what's going on. But so far I got nothing... I suspect 
$$
0\leq \int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u(x,t_2)\,dx\leq \int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u(x,t_1)\,dx\leq \int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u_0(x)\,dx
$$
for $0<t_1<t_2$ but I can not prove it.

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: You posted on Math.SE only 16 hours ago.  It is premature to crosspost.

Comment: A typical "no return" condition that would imply point 1. is the following: $$f(t_0)=0 \Rightarrow f'(t_0)>0.$$I don't know if your function $f$ satisfies it, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge I think it is already $2$ days now! So it should be ok to edit and post it. Thx!

Comment: Do you want a proof that 1 holds for all possible choices of $a$?  Or that there exists some choice of $a$ such that 1 holds?  And similarly regarding 2.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson The properties of $a(x)$ has been given in eq.(3), I don't have more assumptions for it...

Comment: @DavidKetcheson but of course, if you found some special $a(x)$ which makes $1$ and $2$ work, please let me know!

Comment: @DavidKetcheson sorry. Yes, I want a proof that 1 holds for all possible choices of $a$.

Comment: @tankonetoone Is it essential that the dimension $n=2$? As a playground it's possible to consider a one-dimensional periodic case. The solution can be expanded into series. Also if to denote $h(t)=\frac12\int(u-u_0-a)^2\,dx$ then $f(t)=h'(t)$. The sufficient condition on $h$ would be convexity of the graph $y=h(t)$.

Comment: @Andrew 1. Yes, it is important that $n=2$. 2. Yes, $h(t)$ is as you suspect. But what I am trying to prove is $h(t)$ is convex...

Comment: I guess, you have tried to calculate what comes out of this. I mean if $f=0$ at some point this means that $$\partial_t \tfrac12 \|u\|_{L^2}^2 = \partial_t \|u[u_o+a]\|_{L^1}.$$ Now the left hand side is just an $L^2$ norm of a caloric function, and their decay properties are known. The right hand side is a derivative of a weighted $L^1$ norm of $u$. Without the weight this would be constant and its derivative would be zero. The weight of course makes things more complicated, but this is still just an ordinary differential equation, so maybe it is possible to extract something out of this.